# Unity: LoadScene does not work when fired from timer

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my game, when the player dies, a dying sound is played and once the sound is over, the scene is supposed to be reloaded when the user still has enough lives.

Before I had the sound, the play died instantly upon calling the death() function:

```
public static void Death()
{
    AddCoinScript.coinCounter = 0;
    LivesScript.livesCounter--;

        if (LivesScript.livesCounter > -1)//to get 0 live
        {
            Debug.Log("TIMER");

            var currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
        }
        else
        {
            //TO DO GameOver
        }

}
```

This worked like a charm. 
But now I added a death sound to it. Unfortunately, unity doesnt provide an event handler for when the sound is done playing (I want the scene to be reloaded not instantly anymore, but after the death sound is done playing), so I have decided to take it upon myself to just build a timer. The timer fires right after the death sound is over. This is what this function has become:

```
public static void Death()
{
    AddCoinScript.coinCounter = 0;
    LivesScript.livesCounter--;

    PlayDeathSound();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = aSDeath.clip.length * 1000;
    timer.Start();

    timer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        timer.Stop();

        if (LivesScript.livesCounter > -1)//to get 0 live
        {
            Debug.Log("TIMER");

            var currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
        }
        else
        {
            //TO DO GameOver
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see, to make sure the timer REALLY fires, I set up a "debug.Log("TIMER")" to see, if it really works. And guess what: it does. The debug now shows "TIMER" in its console. But you know what doesnt work anymore? The two lines of code right beneath that.

```
            var currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
```

It's the same exact lines that worked just before - but when fired from the timer, they just get ignored? How is this even possible? 
When I change it all back, it works again. Only when the timer fires the two lines, they get ignored.

This is totally odd or am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: You could try setting a bool like `isDead` then check the `AudioSource.isPlaying` in the update. Once that is false and `isDead` is true load the scene

Comment: well, this is what I ended up doing however, this doesnt answer my question, How on earth did the function above not work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I am not an expert on C# and delegate but apparently it creates a separate thread and you can only use `SceneManager.GetActiveScene` on main thread.

Since i am not so sure about `delegate` i will offer an easier solution. You can use a coroutine since you know how much you have to wait like this:

```
public void Death()
{
    StartCoroutine(DeathCoroutine());
}
IEnumerator DeathCoroutine()
{      

    AddCoinScript.coinCounter = 0;
    LivesScript.livesCounter--;
    PlayDeathSound();
    // wait for duration of the clip than continue executing rest of the code
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(aSDeath.clip.length);

    if (LivesScript.livesCounter > -1)//to get 0 live
    {
        Debug.Log("TIMER");

         var currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
         SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
    }
    else
    {
         //TO DO GameOver
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a coroutine ? You just start it when the player dies, and yield while your sound is still playing.